LoadLibraryExW failed error when using procedural macro defined inside crate
I have a crate that included procedural macros defines in a sub crate.  The code has worked fine for years but recently I am getting "LoadLibraryExW failed".  It literally starting giving this error randomly one day with no changes to the code.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Try running cargo clean (or renaming the target directory if you want to keep it for further investigation) and then building again.
